# The code is running OK for 1st and 2nd row.. But after that it is not going for the other rows in SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

this is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    SQLiteDatabase sd;
    Button b1,b2,b3,b4;
    TextView t1,t2;
    int i=1;
    String s;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        sd=openOrCreateDatabase("easyquest", MODE_PRIVATE, null);


        try {
            sd.execSQL("create table easyquest (id int not null ,question varchar not null,option1 varchar not null,option2 varchar not null,option3 varchar not null,option4 varchar not null,answer varchar not null)");
            sd.execSQL("insert into easyquest values(1,'Hitler party which came into power in 1933 is known as','Republic Party','Revolutionist Party','Nazi Party','Swastik Party','Nazi Party')");
            sd.execSQL("insert into easyquest values(2,'What is the name of lead actor of Breaking Bad?','Bryan Cranston','Charlie Sheen','Neil Patrick Harris','Peter Dinklage','Bryan Cranston')");
            sd.execSQL("insert into easyquest values(3,'What is the name of Ted Mosby of How I Met Your Mother in real life','Aaron Paul','Josh Radnor','Neil Patrick Harris,'Walder Schmidt','Josh Radnor')");
            sd.execSQL("insert into easyquest values(4,'Where are the Starks of Game of Thrones located?','West','South','East','North','North')");
            sd.execSQL("insert into easyquest values(5,'How many avengers were there in the Avenger Movie?','5','4','6','7','6')");
            sd.execSQL("insert into easyquest values(6,'What is the name of Charlie Harper's brother in Two and a Half men?','Jake','Alan','Charlie','Walder','Alan')");
            sd.execSQL("insert into easyquest values(7,'What is the Real name of Joey of TV series FRIENDS?','Matthew Perry','Matt le Blanc','David Schwimmer','Ashton Kutcher','Matt le Blanc')");


        } catch (Exception e) {}



        Cursor c=sd.rawQuery("select * from easyquest where id="+i, null);
        while(c.moveToNext()){
            t1.setText(c.getString(0));
            t2.setText(c.getString(1));
            b1.setText(c.getString(2));
            b2.setText(c.getString(3));
            b3.setText(c.getString(4));
            b4.setText(c.getString(5));

            s=c.getString(6);

            i++;
        }


        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(b1.getText().toString().equals(s)){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Right Answer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "i ="+i,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Cursor c=sd.rawQuery("select * from easyquest where id="+i, null);
                    if(c.moveToNext()){

                        t1.setText(c.getString(0));
                        t2.setText(c.getString(1));
                        b1.setText(c.getString(2));
                        b2.setText(c.getString(3));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "I am in while",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        b3.setText(c.getString(4));
                        b4.setText(c.getString(5));

                        s=c.getString(6);

                    }
                    i++;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "i ="+i,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrong Answer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(b2.getText().toString().equals(s)){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Right Answer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "i ="+i,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Cursor c=sd.rawQuery("select * from easyquest where id="+i, null);
                    while(c.moveToNext()){


                        t1.setText(c.getString(0));
                        t2.setText(c.getString(1));
                        b1.setText(c.getString(2));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "I am in while",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        b2.setText(c.getString(3));
                        b3.setText(c.getString(4));
                        b4.setText(c.getString(5));

                        s=c.getString(6);
                    }
                    i++;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "i ="+i,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrong Answer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });

        b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                iwhile(b3.getText().toString().equals(s)){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Right Answer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "i ="+i,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Cursor c=sd.rawQuery("select * from easyquest where id="+i, null);
                    while(c.moveToNext()){

                        t1.setText(c.getString(0));
                        t2.setText(c.getString(1));
                        b1.setText(c.getString(2));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "I am in while",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        b2.setText(c.getString(3));
                        b3.setText(c.getString(4));
                        b4.setText(c.getString(5));

                        s=c.getString(6);
                    }
                    i++;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "i ="+i,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrong Answer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });


        b4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(b4.getText().toString().equals(s)){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Right Answer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "i ="+i,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Cursor c=sd.rawQuery("select * from easyquest where id="+i, null);
                    while(c.moveToNext()){

                        t1.setText(c.getString(0));
                        t2.setText(c.getString(1));
                        b1.setText(c.getString(2));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "I am in while",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        b2.setText(c.getString(3));
                        b3.setText(c.getString(4));
                        b4.setText(c.getString(5));

                        s=c.getString(6);
                    }
                    i++;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "i ="+i,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrong Answer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }

}
```

i don't know why it is not going to the 3rd question. and it is not going in the while also. I dont know what to do. The basic idea is to make a quiz game by posting questions and getting their answers. If the answer is right,then a Toast is printed and it should move to the next question. But if the answer is wrong. Then it will stop.

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {}` is an excellent way to hide any cause of problems in the code. Never ever do that.

Comment: Instead of using a new insert query for each line you can use: `Insert into table blah (col1 , col2 ) VALUES(Blah,blah),(blah1,blah1),...`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the string's closing quote after `Harris`.